# Remove NaN value from a set

Tags: python

Is it possible to easily remove NaN values for a Python Set object?  Given that NaN values do not equal anything (and `float('nan') is float('nan')` is also `False`), you can end up with many NaN values in a Set.

```
>>> a = set( (float('nan'), float('nan'), 'a') )
>>> a
{nan, nan, 'a'}
```

The best I can come up with it to define a function like math.isnan, but that is tolerant of non-float types like:

```
def my_isnan(x):
    try:
        return math.isnan(x)
    except TypeError:
        return False
```

Then you can use a set comprehension like this:

```
>>> {x for x in a if not my_isnan(x)}
{'a'}
```

Comment: Putting NaNs in a set in the first place is a bad idea. They violate the assumptions a set is built upon.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @ValentinLorentz Maybe the sentence that ends with a question mark?

Comment: @StefanPochmann It is answered at the end of the post

Comment: @ValentinLorentz Clearly he doesn't consider that "easily", or else he wouldn't ask. So no, it's not answered.

Comment: @user2357112 Yes, that was my conclusion.  If you can't test something for equality, you can't really use them in sets.  But, other than defining a function like in the question, I could not find another way to get them out of a set.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In practice, you could look at the fact that `nan != nan` as a feature, not a bug:

```
>>> a = {float('nan'), float('nan'), 'a'}
>>> a
{nan, nan, 'a'}
>>> {x for x in a if x==x}
{'a'}
```

On the positive side, no need for a helper function.  On the negative side, if you have a non-nan object which is also not equal to itself, you'll remove that too.

Comment: I knew there had to be some way with resorting to the helper function.  Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Use [pd.notna()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.notna.html#pandas.notna) from pandas, e.g.:

```
In [219]: import pandas as pd

In [220]: a = set((float('nan'), float('nan'), 'a'))

In [221]: a = {x for x in a if pd.notna(x)}

In [222]: a
Out[222]: {'a'}
```

Answer (score 4):

Also you can use `filter`:

```
In[75]: a = set((float('nan'), float('nan'), 'a'))

In[76]: set(filter(lambda x: x == x , a))
Out[76]: {'a'}
```

Answer (score 2):

We can simply use the .remove() method

```
In[1]: a = set([np.nan, "A"])
In[2]: a
Out: {'A', nan}
In[3]: a.remove(np.nan)
In[4]: a
Out: {'A'}
```

Comment: Please consider add some explanation/comments to the code.

Comment: As @Fre_der_ik noted, `remove()` will raise an error if there is no NaN in the set. Use `discard()` instead.

Comment: @Benoît Lebreton Your answer helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot make a comment, so I combine the answers above, with some explanation (for beginners).
Create a set, including NaN (numpy.nan value)

```
In[1]: import numpy as np
In[2]: a = set([np.nan, 'A'])
```

Check the created set as result:

```
In[3]: a
Out: {'A', nan}
```

Discard (better then remove which could lead to KeyError if there is non NaN in the set) NaNs:

```
In[4]: a.discard(np.nan)
```

Check the result:

```
In[5]: a
Out: {'A'}
```