# Return NaN from indexing operation on a pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, nan, series

```
a = pd.Series([0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4])
>>> a.loc[[0,1,2]]
0    0.1
1    0.2
2    0.3
dtype: float64
```

When a non existent index is added to the request along with existing ones, it returns NaN (which is what I need).

```
>>> a.loc[[0,1,2, 5]]
0    0.1
1    0.2
2    0.3
5    NaN
dtype: float64
```

But when I am requesting solely non-existing indices I am getting an error

```
>>> a.loc[[5]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#481>", line 1, in <module>
    a.loc[[5]]
KeyError: 'None of [[5]] are in the [index]'
```

Is there a way to get a NaN there again in order to avoid resorting to a `try/except` solution ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37147735/remove-nan-value-from-a-set I think this should help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `pd.Series.reindex` instead.

```
out = a.reindex([0,1,2, 5])
print(out)

0    0.1
1    0.2
2    0.3
5    NaN
dtype: float64
```

---

```
out = a.reindex([5])
print(out)

5   NaN
dtype: float64
```